# Excel - check if row contains value *more than once*

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I'm using Excel 2010 and I've searched everywhere on this site, but can't find an answer...

I have rows which contain grades for students (numerical values), where the number 0 means they missed a class.

I want the row to be highlighted in one color if they have "0" 3 or 4 times, and in another color if they have "0" 5 times or more.

How do I do it?
I only see averages etc. in Conditional formatting, but I need to check each row for a specific value (0), and highlight the row only if this value occurs 3 times or more.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: This is definitely for superuser.com

Answer (score 2):

1. Select all the rows you want to conditionally highlight.
2. Add a new rule with the "Use a formula..." option
3. To highlight rows with >= 5 zeros, enter this formula 
   `=COUNTIF(1:1,0)>=5`
4. To highlight rows with between 3 and 5 zeros, enter this formula `=AND(COUNTIF(1:1,0)>=3,COUNTIF(1:1,0)<5)`

This assumes your range of rows starts on 1. If it does not, you may or may not have to replace `1:1` with the first row that you want to conditionally highlight, but I'm not positive there.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using Conditional formatting.

- Select the range where you have the grades - I'm supposing this starts in row 2
- In the home tab go to "Conditional Formatting" > "New Rule..." > "Use a formula to determine what cells you want"
- In the formula box, type in the following formula `=OR(COUNTIF(2:2,0) = 3, COUNTIF(2:21,0) = 4)`
- Select the cell coloring for 3 or 4 0's

Then do the same kind of formula for 5 0's - `=COUNTIF(2:2,0) = 5` and select the formatting for that.

Hope this does the trick!!